# Was Amy going to get married before meeting Sheldon?

Tags: the-big-bang-theory

In the show The Big Bang Theory, in season 3 or 4 Sheldon and Amy have a video chat in which Amy tells Sheldon that she already has a guy and she will get married to him.
To this Sheldon doesn't react.
So what happens about this?
Was Amy telling a lie?
I couldn't find the exact episode of this scene.

Comment: You'll need to research this further; Amy only appears in the S3 finale for instance. Please find the correct episode and post the relevant excerpt from the dialogue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure no but I won't make it an answer because I can't confirm.

Comment: Since Sheldon and Amy seems having video chats in numerous episodes, at least you could mention whether it's season 3 or 4 your question refers to..  Anyway, AFAIR, Amy says that because she was mad with Sheldon and needed to get his attention and wanted him to apologize. there was no man in her life that she was gonna marry, Sheldon didn't react because he's Sheldon

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's unclear what OP needs to ask him/her/them self. question is pretty vague on focus and question may needs more clarity. it's pretty much answerable and not opinion based per-se.

Comment: You might be thinking of S4 E15: The Benefactor Factor in which Amy claims she's engaged to a Saudi prince who funded her lab. However, it's unlikely she ever had any actual intentions of marrying him.